# How can I launch a .NET exe in a new process in a cross-platform way?

Tags: .net, mono, monodevelop

I have a .NET application that I need to launch into its own process from another .NET application.  If I only cared about it working on Windows, it's easy, I can just use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start, specify the path to my exe, and I'm good to go.

The trick is, this is for a MonoDevelop addin, so I need to do this is a way that works across platforms, and on Mac and Linux you can't count on the OS knowing what to do with a .NET assembly without some help (ie, calling mono myapp.exe).

Since this is for a MonoDevelop addin, an answer making use of the Mono or MonoDevelop libraries would be acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Process.Start from Mono on a .NET executable, it will be run with Mono automatically. It will not be passed directly to the OS.

Comment: Is this true even on Windows? Running Process.Start from within an app running on Mono 2.10.9 seems to launch the new process using .NET.

Comment: Did you set ShellExecute = false?

Comment: Yes, UseShellExecute = false.

Comment: This might just be on !windows then, not sure.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.ProcessService.StartProcess()